# Encryption using passlib.hash - sha256_crypt.encrypt and decryption

Tags: python-2.7, encryption

I am taking password inputs from user  and planning to use passlib.hash library for encrypting the password .

I am able to encrypt the password successfully and their documentation states about the verify function usage, however I want to find out the original password entered , Is it possible ?

For example :
             User entered a password : abcd
             Password encrypted using passlib to a variable hash 
             How to decrypt the password hash and get value abcd ?

See the sample code below :

```
    print "Enter a password "
    passw = raw_input()
    print "password entered is ", passw
    hash = sha256_crypt.encrypt(passw)
retrivepass=?
```

Is it possible to retrive the original password ? If not what is the best alternative ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrieve the original password?

No. The purpose of a password hashing function is to make it possible for you to authenticate users without actually storing their passwords.

Hashing functions are one-way, so given the output, you cannot infer what the input was. Think of it like adding two numbers together. You know that 2 + 2 = 4, but given 4, you can't figure out that the two numbers that were added together were 2 and 2.

> If not what is the best alternative?

You most likely don't need encryption. You need a good password hashing function, like Bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Answer (score 0):

Store the hash then when the user would like access:

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    passw = raw_input("Enter your password")
    valid = sha256_crypt.verify(passw, hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is the process of encrypting standard blocks of data, which often results in the same length of output, with even infinitely long input. `SHA256` encodes input data into 256 bits of output data.

You can always hash the password and store it. But the password cannot be retrieved back. The ideal way is to get the password again, hash it, and compare it with the stored hashed value.